# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'TerminatedByCompany' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

I inner join 2 table (Termination Reasons with Users) were the two talk to the each other and Termination Reasons table contains 2 column (Id (int) , Name(varchar)) and the other one , Users Table contains 1 column (EmploymentStatusId (int)) .
 I can use EmploymentStatusId(int) from tbl Users  with Id (int) from another table wich is Termination Reasons beacuse , both of them have same data type (int):

```
SELECT 
u AS Status

FROM 
d AS p INNER JOIN d AS u ON u=p
INNER JOIN d AS t ON t = u
WHERE u=214 order by u;
```

But when i try using EmploymentStatusId (int) from tbl Users with Name (varchar) from tbl Termination Reasons , i got problem:

```
SELECT
t AS Status

FROM 
d AS p INNER JOIN db AS u ON u.I=p
INNER JOIN b AS t ON t= u
WHERE u=214 order by u;
```

And then **Error** : 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'TerminatedByCompany' to data type int.

i know why ,because they have different data type  , therefore they can not talk to the each other.
 but i tried also to solve this with  Convert  but idont know ,why or how is not working.Can someone please help or point me in the right direction. Thanks.

The Query ,where i tried with CONVERT ,its look like this:

```
SELECT
CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), t)) as Status

FROM 
db AS p INNER JOIN d AS u ON u =p 
INNER JOIN db AS t ON t.Name = u
WHERE u=214 order by u.FirstName;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve by joining on `t.Name` and `u.EmploymentStatusId` as they are different data types, `varchar` and `int`. When this join is being completed it is trying to implicitly convert `t.Name` into an `int` and it contains data that cannot be converted as the error message shows.

If you are trying to get the employment status of the user with `CustomerId` of `214` I would do something similar to:

```
 SELECT
 t.Name AS Status

 FROM 
 dbo.Paychecks AS p INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS u ON u.Id=p.UserId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.TerminationReasons AS t ON t.Id = u.EmploymentStatusId
 WHERE u.CustomerId=214 order by u.FirstName;
```

If I have missed the point please clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The theory behind this , i wanna know for what reason, employees have terminated

Comment: My suggested query should provide you with that response.

Comment: thank you for this, i have another question ,right now the show all reason for terminated but i just wanna show reason terminated for those who just have EmploymentStatusId = 2 . i know how to do it but i will be 2 where in same line. INNER JOIN dbo.TerminationReasons AS t ON t.Id = u.EmploymentStatusId where u.EmploymentStatusId = 2 WHERE u.CustomerId=214 order by u.FirstName;

Comment: If you want to add multiple `WHERE` conditions you need to specify each one followed by an `AND` constraint as they both need to be true:

`SELECT
 t.Name AS Status

 FROM 
 dbo.Paychecks AS p INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS u ON u.Id=p.UserId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.TerminationReasons AS t ON t.Id = u.EmploymentStatusId
WHERE u.CustomerId=214
AND u.EmploymentStatusId = 2
order by u.FirstName;`

Comment: You do not need the second `WHERE`, just use the `AND`